# Connecting site to database

Tags: sql

Is it possible to connect a site that is hosted on the internet to a database that's on my pc?
I have connected a site in such a way when i hosting the site too, but now it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Lool, why don't you just import the remote DB to your PC?

Comment: The database already is on my pc. I'm asking if there's a way to connect the site to it without uploading the database to the site.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hosting package it should also include either a SQL Server database or a MySQL database that you can use to connect to your site. I would recommend against using a local database stored on your computer beyond anything local. Once you move to "production" your database should also be it's own server. I never used local database on a site other than testing it because to me it seems like a risky move and include the possibility if someone hacks your computer they will have access to everything.

Comment: Yes, it does include SQL database, but when i try to upload it after creating a .sql file, it always gives me errors

Comment: You shouldn't have to upload anything SQL related to your site. If you're using PHP you should only have to set up a connection using a username and password along with the server name, database name, table name, etc. Same thing for C# you can use a web service and use `Linq-to-SQL` to directly connect to a stored procedure. Using a stored procedure is better than a direct query in your code. Both SQL Server and MySQL have stored procedures you can create to easily call them pass in parameters and they will handle the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Your IP address is likely dynamic, which means it will change from time to time, making a connection from the internet back down to your PC unreliable. This may also be blocked by your modem and/or router. It would also be very slow, relatively speaking.

Under nearly all circumstances, you will be much happier if you host your database on the server with your site.

If you really want to host it on your PC, you will need to run software locally to run a database such as mySQL. This is likely to mean an OS of linux. Once you have that set up, you just need to set your database host to point at your IP instead of something like localhost. But really, this is a lot more trouble than it is worth - you already have a server to put it on.

**edit:**
You mention in response to another answer that you want to do this because you are getting errors when you try to import the sql to the server. I would strongly suggest solving the errors instead of using a local DB. For any live service, you will need it to be on the server, and its better to solve the error earlier than later, so that the fix is as simple to implement as possible!

Comment: Well, i would love to be able to upload it on the server, but it always gives me errors, like parsing errors and i don't really know why.

Comment: @VicentiuGabriel: Maybe you could post a chunk of your sql here for us to help you solve that issue, rather than trying to find a hack around the real problem.

Comment: I will post the whole error tomorrow as i don't have access to my computer right now. Thanks for the help.